# Como fazer uma session

Tags: php, mysql, session, login

Tenho um sistema que tem uma página de login, mas ela só vê se existe aquele email e senha que o usuário digitou no banco de dados e libera pra página principal.

Agora eu precisava criar uma página de perfil pra esse usuário então o sistema precisa saber mais do que se tem um usuário logado, mas sim qual usuário está logado pra jogar as informações dele em uma página de perfil.

Essas são duas coisas que eu não sei: fazer o sistema reconhecer qual usuário está logado e colocar essas informações numa página de perfil.

**Essa é a minha página de login:**

```
            <section id="hello" class="home bg-mega">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="main_home">
                            <div class="home_text">
                                <h1 class="text-white">INTYME <br/> LOGIN</h1>
                            </div>
                            <form method="post" action="validacao.php" style=" 
                            background-color: #7a494994;
                            padding-bottom: 20px;
                            padding-top: 20px;
                            padding-left: 10px;
                            padding-right: 10px;"
                            >
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label style="color:#ffffff">Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EMAIL" name="EMAIL"  placeholder="Insira aqui o seu e-mail">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label style="color:#ffffff">Senha</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="SENHA" name="SENHA"  placeholder="Insira aqui a sua senha">
                                </div>
                                    <a href="inicial.php" class="btn btn-primary m-top-20">Entrar</a>
                                    <a href="cadastro.php" class="btn btn-primary m-top-20">Cadastre-se</a>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

**Essa é a minha página de validação de login:**

```
<?php
//Esse login ficou meio complicadinho, então vou deixar comentado: 
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Primeiro verifica se o post não está vazio
if (!empty($_POST) AND !empty($_POST['EMAIL']) OR !empty($_POST['SENHA'])) {
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('intyme');
    // Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EMAIL']);
    $senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SENHA']);
    $ativo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ATIVO']);
    //$senha = md5($senha);

    $sql = "SELECT `ID`, `EMAIL`, `SENHA`, `ATIVO`  FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`EMAIL` = '". $email ."') AND (`SENHA` = '". $senha ."')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
      // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
      echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
    } else {
      $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
      // Verifica se o usuário é 0 ou 1

      if ($resultado['ativo'] == 0) { header("Location: inicial.php"); } 
      else { header("Location: inicial.php"); }

      exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual é a relação de sessão e PDO a que se refere? São coisas distintas.

Comment: Tu precisa armazenar o ID do usuário na sessão e então usar esse ID para fazer um select trazendo as informações referentes aquele usuário.

Comment: Aconselho vivamente a utilizar `password_hash` e `password_verify` para não guardar as passwords em claro no banco e evitar compromete-las em situações de brechas. Como aparte, `if` e `else` redirecionando para a mesma página `header("Location: inicial.php");` não faz sentido

Comment: Ah, eles tão redirecionando pra mesma página porque eu fiz esse login com permissão, mas eu ainda não tenho uma página de ADM então coloquei pra as duas redirecionarem pro mesmo lugar por enquanto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar uma linha aqui:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
  // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
  echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
} else {
  $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  // Verifica se o usuário é 0 ou 1

  $_SESSION["login"] = $resultado["id"] //Cria uma sessão com o id do usuário

  if ($resultado['ativo'] == 0) { header("Location: inicial.php"); } 
  else { header("Location: inicial.php"); }

  exit;
}
```

Depois quando precisar é só buscar os dados do usuário logado pelo id

Para usar sessões é necessário chamar `session_start()`, sugiro que faça isso na primeira linha do php:

```
<?php
session_start();
//...
```

Leia mais na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Então, eu fui tentar ir usar esse session_start(); na minha página de perfil e dar uns echos $_SESSION['EMAIL'] por exemplo, mas nada apareceu. Sabe me dizer por que?

Comment: Você chamou `session_start()` em todas as páginas que é usado sessões?

Comment: Sim, eu chamei.

Comment: Coloque `session_start()` na primeira linha, se não colocou.  Depois verifica se quando criado a sessão com email o valor da variável email não estava vazio

Comment: Gente, o erro era na página que eu faço o login e não na session, a session tava funcionando perfeitinha.